# Replace a string in a file that contains a specific character with "sed" in mac OS

Tags: macos, sed

I was trying to replace any string that consists of `(0)` into `other` in a file. for example, If the file has the following lines:

```
apple(0)
apple(20)
orange(70)
banana(0)
```

In Linux, I can do it by sed `'s/\S*\((0)\)\S*/other/g' file`. Then, the file will be modified into below:

```
other
apple(20)
orange(70)
other
```

I want to do the same thing in Mac OS X as well but it does not work. What is the variant for this case in mac OS? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `\S` is a GNU extension and can be substituted by `[^[:blank:]]`
in a posix-compliant manner.

Would you please try:

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]]*(0)[^[:blank:]]*/other/g' file
```

(Note that the outer parens to generate capture group is meaningless (harmless) and removed.)

Contents of `file`:

```
apple(0)
apple(20)
orange(70)
banana(0)
ABC apple(0)
```

Output of the `sed` command above:

```
other
apple(20)
orange(70)
other
ABC other
```

I have verified the `sed` command with the `--posix` switch.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. Just checked and `[^[:blank:]]` is the correct one for `posix`. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. BTW the outermost parens seem to be unnecessary in this context as you do not use the back reference in the replacement. I've updated my answer by simplifying it.